# c# Reading XML with repeated elements into DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I am trying to read an XML file into a DataSet using DataSet.ReadXML.
The problem is that some of the nodes have repeating elements with the same name.These repeating elements are being ignored when imported into the dataset.

For example:

```
<node1>
    ---
    <element>valueA</element>
    <element>valueB</element>
</node1>
<node2>
    ---
    <element>valueA</element>
    <element>valueC</element>
</node2>
```

Any suggestions or assistance are welcome.

Comment: Are you fixed on using a `DataSet` or can we suggest alternative approaches?

Comment: Any suggestions, alternatives or otherwise are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Data.DataSet` is probably not the user-friendly way of consuming XML data, especially when you don't have a schema readily available. Various alternatives are available, probably the simplest one is using classes from the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace (available in .NET 3.5+), e.g.:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(YOUR_XML);
//get contents of all `element` elements in `node1` as list
var result = xDoc.Root.Descendants("node1")
                      .Single()
                      .Elements("element")
                      .Select(el => el.Value)
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Almost there. I have a large number of elements to read and process and am still unsure as to how to go about processing the input XML file. Do you think it would be better to the read the file using one of the alternatives like the XMLReader?

Comment: @user3081814 The question you probably need to ask yourself - is my volume of data still reasonable to hold in memory? If the answer is yes (and considering the amounts of memory readily available, it might be a non-issue), I'd avoid giving it much thought, unless you either predict the data volume to grow or simply want a programistic exercise. If no, `XmlReader` might be a better choice.